# AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed - c#. Ошибка при инициализации проекта

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Всем привет.
Я переписывал архитектуру проекта, и как закончил, получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
"AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Implemantation.IServices.IOrderService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Implemantation.Services.OrderService': Unable to resolve service for type 'DBInfrastructure.TRepository`1[DBInfrastructure.DTOModels.OrderModel]' while attempting to activate 'Implemantation.Services.OrderService'.)"

"InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Implemantation.IServices.IOrderService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Implemantation.Services.OrderService': Unable to resolve service for type 'DBInfrastructure.TRepository`1[DBInfrastructure.DTOModels.OrderModel]' while attempting to activate 'Implemantation.Services.OrderService'."

"AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Implemantation.IServices.IOrderService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Implemantation.Services.OrderService': Unable to resolve service for type 'DBInfrastructure.TRepository`1[DBInfrastructure.DTOModels.OrderModel]' while attempting to activate 'Implemantation.Services.OrderService'.)"
```

Вот Sturtup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<TRepository<OrderModel>, OrderRepository>();

            services.AddTransient<IOrderService, OrderService>();
        }
```

Вот OrderService:

```
public class OrderService : IOrderService
    {
        public readonly Random Randomizer = new();
        private readonly TRepository<OrderModel> orderRepository;

        public OrderService(TRepository<OrderModel> orderRepository)
        {
            this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
        }
    }
```

Вот TRepository:

```
public class TRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        public ISchema Schema { get; set; }
        public ISpace Space { get; set; }
        public IIndex PrimaryIndex { get; set; }
        protected Box box { get; set; }
        private bool disposedValue;

        public  TRepository( Box box, string vspace, string viindex)
        {
            this.box = box;
            _ = Init(vspace, viindex);
        } // ctor
        private async Task Init(string vspace, string viindex)
        {
            Schema = box.GetSchema();
            Space = await box.GetSchema().GetSpace(vspace);
            PrimaryIndex = await Space.GetIndex(viindex);
        } // init func
    }
```

Вот IRepository:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T: class
    {
        public T FindById<Y>(Y id);
        public IEnumerable<T> FindAll();
        public Task Create(T model);
        public Task Delete(T model);
        public Task Update(T moodel);
    }
```

Вот OrderRepository:

```
public class OrderRepository : TRepository<OrderModel>
    {
        public OrderRepository(Box box) : base(box, vspace, viindex) { }

        private readonly static string vspace = "orders";
        private readonly static string viindex = "primary_index";
    }
```

Ошибка возникает при запуске веб приложения.
Вот скриншот ошибки:
[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Comment: Не в тему, но вы забыли, что можно `const string` делать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public OrderRepository(Box box)` - конструктор просит какой-то `Box`. Но вы не зарегистрировали этот класс в контейнере. Следовательно контейнер не знает, что именно надо подсунуть в конструктор и дает исключение.